# Creating a regex redirect rule based on parameter in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to create a htaccess 302 redirect rule which should work as follows:

```
http://domain.com/projects/this_can_be_whatever/identifier_2/identifier_3/
```

redirect to:

```
http://domain.com/assignments/identifier_2_identifier_3/
```

So basically it removes `this_can_be_whatever` and combines the last two identifiers / folders with an underscore instead of a "/".

Edit:  I just noticed that my client has changed the links on their site :( I've updated the URL structure above. Sorry for this.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)(\/[^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/$ $1_new_name$2/$3_$4 [L]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^projects/(?:.+)/(.+)/(.+)/$ http://domain.com/assignments/$1_$2/ [R=302,L]
```

should work

Comment: Had to edit the question as my client has changed their structure just recently unfortunately :( The question is updated. Any idea how the above could be accomplished aswell?

Comment: You sir, are a saint :) Thank you!